# How to update values in Cloud Firestore from Flutter at midnight

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have an app which tracks a users mood. I am wanting to reset the mood icons, which they have chosen, at midnight. I display them using `display: true` in cloud firestore and I am wanting all of the values to be set to `false` at midnight.
I have looked around and noticed that most of the answers mention using schedule but I wasn't wanting to have to pay for this. Are there any other options that anyone may be able to suggest?

Comment: What does Flutter have to do with this? You don’t want to change it *from* Flutter. 
Anyway, you can always set up your own scheduled function somewhere else, and either access Firestore with IAM, or create a callable cloud function and update the value from there.

Comment: @Riwen hi thanks for your comment however, I am wanting to change it from Flutter which is why I'm asking if it is possible. I will have a look at having a function somewhere else though, thank you.

Comment: Hi @ajnabz could you elaborate a bit more into why an scheduler is not the correct path?

Comment: Hi @LouisC it's just as my project is for university and so we aren't supposed to spend any money. All the information I have seen mentions that I would need to upgrade to Blaze and this seems to cost extra. I might be wrong but this is just what I have found